# Canvas HTML 5 drawing circles at each end of a line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**EDIT:** I figured out a solution http://jsfiddle.net/rwuvnrau/1 should I close or would this be helpful?

I am playing around with canvas, and am trying out an interesting line within my website.

I am starting to figure out how the `bezierCurveTo` function works, I still need to refine it a bit, but as a design concept I would like to draw bordered circles(without a middle, similar to the chat and play icon in the screen below) at the end of each points of the line.

I am not sure  how to go about this, the only thing I can think of is since I know the `P0` position `context.moveTo(850, 0);` 850 I could draw the circle at that coordinate

[image]

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = 970;
  canvas.height = 600;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(850, 0);
  context.bezierCurveTo(850, 378, 0, 185, 3, 492);
  context.lineWidth = 2;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#4285f4';
  context.stroke();
```

It's been awhile but I think to create a new object I can just do `context.beginPath()` then build a circle. I need to research this and make a fiddle but I hope someone can help me out quickly.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwuvnrau/)

Comment: Not sure if I should close or what, but I figured it out http://jsfiddle.net/rwuvnrau/1/ advice pls.

Comment: Since you went off to ask in the first place, you should post an answer with the code. Let the community decide whether the question is relevant enough to live on.

Comment: Gotcha, I have the fiddle, but you're right I should add the code here.

Answer (score 1):

So I shouldn't have asked without trying first, but I wasn't confident in my canvas skills. This may come in handy for some.

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 10;



  canvas.width = 970;
  canvas.height = 600;

  // curved line
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(850, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(850, 378, 0, 185, 3, 492);
  context.lineWidth = 2;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#4285f4';
  context.stroke();

  // circle
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(850, 90, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'transparent';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = '#4285f4';
  context.stroke();
```

Canvas really is all about math, and knowing the coordinates for your objects. Since I knew my starting point for my line was on the x axis at 850px I could do `context.arc(850, 90, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);` the y axis was 90 for the circle because the y axis for my starting point was 100 and the radius is 10.

In this version of my code I didn't consider the stoke width so add 2px to your equation, working fine on my site, not sure if I want to implement this though lol.